# Webview loading only first time

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I have a activty which has viewpager and a button . Onclick of button moving to the OutletMapWebView activity with respective needed parameter(viewpager data) ,Below is the code of

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pd = (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 11)? new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this) : new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Panel);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.outletMapWebView);

  //  String MAP_URL = "<html><body><iframe width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' style='border:0' src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyD7mjSU3lSzYHgGcUglDog9cxLNjZDq_68&origin=12.9312987,77.5154981&destination=217 East Coast Road, Singapore&mode=driving'></iframe> </body></html>";
    String jala_kayu = "<html><body><iframe width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' style='border:0' src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyD7mjSU3lSzYHgGcUglDog9cxLNjZDq_68&origin=12.9313121,77.5154951&destination=269 Jalan Kayu, Singapore&mode=driving'></iframe> </body></html>";
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, jala_kayu, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        pd.setMessage("");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); // updated jul 3
        pd.setCancelable(true);  // updated jul 3
        if (!isFinishing()) // updated jul 3
            pd.show();
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.w("mCurrentUrl",""+url);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    // Here the page loading will stop so dismiss the ProgressDialog
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // this is what we should do
        webView.invalidate();
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.gc();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        webView.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

The code is perfectly working for first click , the google map inside webview opens , but after that on going back and changed the viewpager and again if i click the button . the webview showing blank white screen . I have checked all bundled data , even checked map url in browser . it works . but inside webview it is not working . I think there is something related to webview not refreshing after first time . Please help . .Thank you in advance

Comment: Checked in Lolipop and below , working fine , But above lolipop version not working . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code : `webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`